# How to simulate an analog stop watch in Android Watch Face?

Tags: android-wear-2.0, watch-face-api

I'm developing a realistic chronograph watch with Android Wear OS. I already have a seconds hand watch working well, and a stoped chronograph hand. When I tap on the watch, I want my chronograph hand start from zero, but it is starting from the actual second.

**My question is:** How can I apply a shift value to my chronograph rotate in order to discount the actual second, and the hand start from 0 position?

Here is the actual behavior:

[image]

Here is the code that rotate the small seconds hand:

```
private float getSecondsRotation() {
            final float seconds =
                    (mCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) + mCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) / 1000f);
            return seconds * 6f;
        }
```

Is there any way to passing a `shift` parameter for that method and discount from the result?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried to run this code, but hopefully it gives you an idea of how to approach your problem.

```
// True when the chronograph is running, false otherwise
private boolean isChronographRunning = false;

// The second when the chronograph is started
private float secondOffset = 0f;

// Called when the user taps on the watch face
private void startChronograph() {
    isChronographRunning = true;
    secondOffset = mCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) + mCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) / 1000f;
}

// Called from your draw loop if(isChronographRunning)
private float getChronographRotation() {
    float currentSecond = mCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) + mCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) / 1000f;
    float chronographSecond = currentSecond - secondOffset;
    return chronographSecond * 6f;
}
```